# Own Configuration of Spring Cloud LoadBalancerClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, load-balancing

I want to do my own configuration for the Spring Cloud LoadBalancerClient (Package org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient). However, the configuration is not applied, Round Robin is used by default.

Can anyone help me further?

```
public class CustomLoadBalancerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ReactorLoadBalancer<ServiceInstance> randomLoadBalancer(Environment environment,
                                                            LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory) {
        String name = environment.getProperty(LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME);
        return new RandomLoadBalancer(loadBalancerClientFactory
                .getLazyProvider(name, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class),
                name);
    }

}


public class Client {


    @Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;


    @LoadBalanced
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


    private String getBaseUrl() {
        ServiceInstance serviceInstance = loadBalancerClient.choose("eventService");
        System.out.println(serviceInstance);
        return serviceInstance.getUri().toString();
    }
   
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getAll() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String url = getBaseUrl()+"/xx";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Spring Cloud* documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/#custom-loadbalancer-configuration), when you create a Custom Load Balancer Configuration, you need to add the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@LoadBalancerClient(value = "stores", configuration = CustomLoadBalancerConfiguration.class)
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

So it can be used.